# Android Log class

Tags: java, android

That might be pretty obvious to everyone since I havn't seen a thread about it but I would like to know where the output of all the Log methods (Log.e,Log.d etc..) would be, in the console?LogCat?Some log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Log` classes log to LogCat.